# Delphi XE8 Get Web Data RaiseError

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe8

Good Morning,I have a confused problem.I'm writing a multi-device application to get data from web server. I'm Using Rad Studio XE8.When the application running, it raise error  like this
**Debugger Exception Notification
Project SmartManager.apk raised exception class Segmentation fault (11).**

1.I create a WSDL Importer,the WSDL file location is 'http://60.12.81.154/MobileQueryService/services/MobileQueryDaoImpl?wsdl'
2.Add a button and two edit component to the app .The button Onclick event is to finish user login,the code is:

**

```
procedure TFrmUserLogin.LoginByWebService;
var
  ret: string;
  JSONObject: TJSONObject;
begin
  try
    ret := GetMobileQueryDaoImplPortType.Sys_Return_UserInfo(eUserNo.Text, ePwd.Text);
    if ret <> '' then
    begin
      JSONObject := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ret), 0) as TJSONObject;

    ...
    end;
  except
  showmessage('login failure!')
  end;
end;
```

**

when the APP Run to '`ret := GetMobileQueryDaoImplPortType.Sys_Return_UserInfo(eUserNo.Text, ePwd.Text);`',it raise error "class Segmentation fault (11)".

3.The webserver is writen by Java ,running on Tomcat7,when the app raise error,I find the server is running Normal.I print the result,it is right.

4.this app is running normal on win32 or win64 platform,but when i switch to android,the error is raised.
5.I have tested 2 mobile phone.One is HuaWei P6, the Android version 4.2.The Other is HuaWei P9, the Android version is 6.0. The App is working OK on P6,but raised error On P9.
6.Yesterday,I tried another way to get data from wbeserver By using httpclient,
the code like this:

**

```
procedure TFrmUserLogin.LoginByHttp;
var HttpClient:TIDHttp;
    ParamList:TStringList;
    url:String;
    retResponse:TStringStream;
     i: Integer;
  rt,ret: string;
begin
try
  HttpClient:=TIdHTTP.Create(Application.Owner);
  retResponse:=TStringStream.Create;
  url:='http://60.12.81.154/MobileQueryService/servlet/UserLoginAction' ;
  ParamList:=TStringList.Create;
  ParamList.Add('userno='+eUserNo.Text);
  ParamList.Add('password='+ePwd.Text);
  HttpClient.Post(url,ParamList,retResponse);
  ...
end;
```

**

The error is same!!!

**Then I replace `'HttpClient.Post(url,ParamList,retResponse);`' 
with 
'`HttpClient.Get(url+'?userno='+eUserNo.Text+'&password='+ePwd.Text,retResponse);`'**
It is working as expected.
I do not know why,can anyone help me ?
 I debugged the problem and it stops at the following line of code in  "System.pas" file :
 dlclose(handle);
I found when the handle is 0,the error raised.And I checked the file in XE10,all the code using dlclose will check that weather the handle is 0，like this :
if handle<>0 then  dlclose(handle);

Could it be said that it is a bug of XE8?

Comment: In my experience a class Segmentation fault (11)[android/ios]. is almost equal to a Access Violation in VCL terms, this might mean that the reference to GetMobileQueryDaoImplPortType.Sys_Return_UserInfo is  not properly instantiated/broken

Comment: @Ryno Coetzee The same code GetMobileQueryDaoImplPortType.Sys_Return_UserInfo works properly on Android 4.X. Even I change to HTTPCLient.POST,the error still exists.SO I think the XE8 dose not compatible with platform Android 6.X .